# Visual Studio - Azure Dev : failed to push the branch to the remote repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm using VS2019 and Azure DevOps. I'm no expert at all on source control and i've only been using Azure Devops as a backup of my projects.

I recently had to have my computer reinstalled and started a new project. But when trying to push to Azure DevOps i'm getting the following error:

`Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.`

`Pushing master`

`Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. unable to update url base from redirection: asked for: https://dev.azure.com/...../info/refs?service=git-receive-pack redirect: https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?`

It seems i'm being redirected to the signin page. But i'm signed in in Visual Studio and i'm seeing other projects. How can i solve this?

Comment: Do you have Git for Windows installed? If yes, did you install the Git Credential Manager (either Core or regular)?

Comment: I installed Git for Windows with the Git Credential Manager Core

Comment: Are you able to push from the command line? Or do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your local credentials are mixed after reinstalled the computer, please clear the stored TFS credentials in Visual Studio 2017 and Git credentials by following below steps.

- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService`.
- Clear TFS caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`
- Clear all the browser caches especially for the stored password
- Look in the **Windows Credential manager** and remove the TFS related credentials and Git credentials there
  [image]
- Restart **Visual Studio > Team Explorer > Manage Connections** to check if the `Enter credential dialog` popup. Just try this several times or restart VS to popup it again.
- Enter the user password, then **Team Explorer > Manage Connections** to connect to target project. See this [thread](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F47188210%2Fclear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cbf4a354f75ee4552d24808d8c332312f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473967628186365%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=OluNmxtqjBsQwXHQEqGsq%2BLIly3FpfCLqHRFNjvrw5k%3D&reserved=0) for more details.

In addition, you could follow this doc: [Connect from Visual Studio or Team Explorer](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Fprojects%2Fconnect-to-projects%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dvisual-studio-2019%23connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cbf4a354f75ee4552d24808d8c332312f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637473967628196355%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=%2FghdgcP5DgzK5l%2BNdAWzoZAht9BMoKoMI7miMRRBSQc%3D&reserved=0) to get more guidance.

**Update**
If your [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels) is Stakeholder in this organization, you cannot contribute to Azure Repositories. And members of Project Collection Administrators group can change access level.

Comment: I am able to pull projects and download them. I'm "only" not able to push a new project.
I followed your steps to clear all settings, i signed in but the result is the same.
@TTT command line gives the same error

Comment: Please a. follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops to check your repository permissions in this particular project, make sure that there are all allow permissions. b. check if you install extensions which might causes this issue. c. check if you can create branch and make commits directly via web portal. d. check if there are proxy/firewall which might cause this issue.

Comment: I can create a new project in the web portal. I'm project admin of the newly created project but i have no permission to create or access a repository. When i want to check the permissions i'm getting "You don't have the authority to view the permissions for this object"

Comment: Please check if your [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops), make sure that you are not a **Stakeholder** in this organization. And then check if you are [a member of the Project Collection Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#show-members-of-the-project-collection-administrators-group).

Comment: The access level did it. Not sure why. I'm "Organization Owner" but was my access level was "Stakeholder". Changed it to Basic and i can push. Didn't really look at that settings because everything worked before the reinstallation of my computer so I assumed the problem was a setting on my computer. No settings where changed online except the url that was changed from xxx.visualstudio.com to dev.azure.com/xxx (the "Use the new Url"-setting). Not sure how i can mark your comment as the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have updated my answer, so you could mark it as the answer, thanks.